# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class using REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, cxf

I have an project with my models and DAOs and other with my REST configurations

My model class has those dependencies

```
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.5</aspectj.version>
    <cglib-nodep.version>3.1</cglib-nodep.version>
    <embedmongo.version>1.46.4</embedmongo.version>
    <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>5.1.3.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <javax.el.version>2.2.6</javax.el.version>
    <jodatime.version>2.6</jodatime.version>
    <maven-antrun.version>1.7</maven-antrun.version>
    <maven-assembly.version>2.5.3</maven-assembly.version>
    <maven-checkstyle.version>2.13</maven-checkstyle.version>
    <maven-clean.version>2.6.1</maven-clean.version>
    <maven-compiler.version>3.2</maven-compiler.version>
    <maven-dependency.version>2.9</maven-dependency.version>
    <maven-deploy.version>2.8.2</maven-deploy.version>
    <maven-enforcer.version>1.3.1</maven-enforcer.version>
    <maven-findbugs.version>3.0.0</maven-findbugs.version>
    <maven-jar.version>2.5</maven-jar.version>
    <maven-javadoc.version>2.10.1</maven-javadoc.version>
    <maven-jxr.version>2.5</maven-jxr.version>
    <maven-install.version>2.5.2</maven-install.version>
    <maven-pmd.version>3.3</maven-pmd.version>
    <maven-project-info-reports.version>2.8</maven-project-info-reports.version>
    <maven-release.version>2.5.1</maven-release.version>
    <maven-resources.version>2.7</maven-resources.version>
    <maven-site.version>3.4</maven-site.version>
    <maven-surefire.version>2.18</maven-surefire.version>
    <maven-taglist.version>2.4</maven-taglist.version>
    <maven-versions.version>2.1</maven-versions.version>
    <maven-war.version>2.6</maven-war.version>
    <mongodriver.version>2.12.5</mongodriver.version>
    <morphia.version>0.109</morphia.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <proxytoys.version>1.0</proxytoys.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <testng.version>6.8.21</testng.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib-nodep.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>${embedmongo.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.el.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${jodatime.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <version>${mongodriver.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
        <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
        <version>${morphia.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.proxytoys</groupId>
        <artifactId>proxytoys</artifactId>
        <version>${proxytoys.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My REST project has those dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <cxf.version>3.0.1</cxf.version>
    <cxf-jaxrs.version>2.7.13</cxf-jaxrs.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
    <jaxws.version>2.2.8</jaxws.version>
    <jaxws-api.version>2.2.11</jaxws-api.version>
    <json.version>20141113</json.version>
    <maven-compiler.version>3.2</maven-compiler.version>
    <maven-enforcer.version>1.3.1</maven-enforcer.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <services-model.version>1.0.0</services-model.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>services-model</artifactId>
        <version>${services-model.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf-jaxrs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxws-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxws.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxws.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>${json.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I run in my machine I receive the following message:

```
Mar 13, 2015 1:28:08 PM org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.OldSpringSupport logWarning
WARNING: DEPRECATED_IMPORT
Mar 13, 2015 1:28:17 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jaxRsServer' defined in class br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server]: Factory method 'jaxRsServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5162)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server]: Factory method 'jaxRsServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2472)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:854)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2663)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3067)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:408)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:117)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:165)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:134)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:119)
at br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig.jaxRsServer(CXFConfig.java:47)
at br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$38969637.CGLIB$jaxRsServer$1(<generated>)
at br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$38969637$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e9f55bcf.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
at br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$38969637.jaxRsServer(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
... 24 more

Mar 13, 2015 1:28:17 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jaxRsServer' defined in class br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server]: Factory method 'jaxRsServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5162)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server]: Factory method 'jaxRsServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2472)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:854)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2663)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3067)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:408)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:117)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:165)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:134)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:119)
at br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig.jaxRsServer(CXFConfig.java:47)
at br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$38969637.CGLIB$jaxRsServer$1(<generated>)
at br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$38969637$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e9f55bcf.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
at br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$38969637.jaxRsServer(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
... 24 more

Mar 13, 2015 1:28:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jaxRsServer' defined in class br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server]: Factory method 'jaxRsServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5162)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server]: Factory method 'jaxRsServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2472)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:854)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2663)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3067)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:408)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:117)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:165)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:134)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:119)
at br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig.jaxRsServer(CXFConfig.java:47)
at br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$38969637.CGLIB$jaxRsServer$1(<generated>)
at br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$38969637$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e9f55bcf.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
at br.com.myapp.spring.CXFConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$38969637.jaxRsServer(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
... 24 more

Mar 13, 2015 1:28:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 13, 2015 1:28:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/service-user] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 13, 2015 1:28:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 13, 2015 1:28:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 13, 2015 1:28:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 13, 2015 1:28:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 14280 ms
```

I read some people saying about cglib others saying about asm however I just dont found my problem. I remove my local application server, download all my .m2 and nothing. The strange part is that the same project run in other machines.

Comment: I guess that is some problem with Tomcat runtime and some conflict with I some library. I tried the same project in same machine with Jetty and worked.